# Call a method using a variable containing the method name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to declare a click handler using an array of strings which contains the selectors and corresponding methods to call:

```
['start','clear','stop','plus','minus'].forEach(function(el) {
    $("#" + el).click(function() { 
        Timer.el();     
    });
});
```

The point is to change `Timer."array[index]"();`. I tried `el` but the console shows an error.

Comment: It's a case of bracket notation vs dot notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically call a method of an object you need to use bracket notation. Try this:

```
['start','clear','stop','plus','minus'].forEach(function(el) {
    $("#" + el).click(function() { 
        Timer[el](); 
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nauqe6h0/)